# Spring JDBC specify table for query at runtime

Tags: mysql, spring, jdbc

My application dynamically creates tables, and I don't know how to read a table using Spring jdbc without hard coding it into the string query. I was thinking about something like this:

```
jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM ?", new Object[] { tableName }, new TableMapper());
```

But spring doesn't like the question mark :-(

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5):

Try `String query = String.format("SELECT * FROM %s", tableName);`

Answer (score 4):

A word of explanation: `Spring` is not the one to blame here, the exception is thrown all the way from your DB driver. `PreparedStatement` doesn't allow parametrising the table name, you can apply the `?` to query parameters only. As noted in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16183318/1240557), the only way to go around this is to insert it into the query string.